# ASP.NET Core Container Requires Certificate?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, rider, azure-web-app-for-containers

#### Background

I have a web application written in ASP.NET Core 8. The application is running from a Docker container.

However, when I run on my machine it throws an error on startup (Rider IDE):

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.

If I disable the HTTPS endpoint, it loads and goes to authenticate, but because I use Azure AD (Entra ID?) as my identity provider, it sends "**http**://{myapp}/signin-oidc" as the URL, which Azure balks at.

**NOTE:** Interestingly, it runs OK in Visual Studio but not in JetBrains Rider...

#### Solution Ideas and Open Issues

1. Load and manage a certificate within the app for HTTPS so that IDP will work: This means I'd have to create a certificate (and maintain it, meaning automation), store it in a key vault, and load on startup. It's also kinda wasted given that Azure Web Apps provides a cert.
2. Configure the container for HTTP only and eventually use an App Gateway for HTTPS when I publish to Azure: But HTTP isn't a valid redirect URI in Azure so it'll never authenticate.

Perhaps there's some documentation I'm missing on how this is supposed to work but I haven't found any recommendations.